# What are those "splash" screens called?

Tags: anime-production

They usually happen on cliffhanger scenes, placed before a commercial or at the end of an episode. Kind of acts like a summary of the scene in one still shot, stylized different than the rest of the animation.

Examples:
[image]
[image]

Video examples to give context [here](https://youtu.be/VnAd8x6kL40?t=135) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDzFCJDTLhk). They happen at the very end of the videos.

Comment: Screens shown before and after a commercial break are called [Eye Catch](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EyeCatch) but that doesn't fit your examples. The closest thing I have found would be [Pastel Chalked Freeze Frame](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PastelChalkedFreezeFrame).

Comment: That "Pastel" page you linked had the term, "harmony cel," which is what I was looking for. Most harmony cels I've seen have that pastel effect to emphasize the shot as different than the rest of the animation, but I imagine there are some that don't have the effect. Thanks!